# how to send the data in request body as json to resttemplate.exchange

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

Assume I am getting the values from one API, need to send that data to other API through `resttemplate.exchange`

I am iterating the values like below

```
String Data="";
for(String value: receivedvalues){
Data=Data.concat(","+val)
}

List<map> result=resttemplate.exchange(url+Data,HttpMethod.GET,ArrayList.class).getBody);
```

The above problem is I'm adding data to request url, but i need to send through the request body but in this case how we can send data through the resttemplate.exchange.Can any one have any idea on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Map your JSON object to POJO class and then use `RestTemplate.exchange(...) method`.

Usage example:

```
ReceivedValuesClass receivedValuesPojo = mapJson(receivedValues);

RequestEntity request = RequestEntity
    .get(new URI(url))
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(receivedValuesPojo);

ResponseClass result=resttemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,ResponseClass.class).getBody;
```

More information here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-org.springframework.http.RequestEntity-java.lang.Class-